# How to check whether the cursor is in an eclipse editor part?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin

I need to find out whether the cursor is inside my tree (tree extends `org.eclipse.ui.EditorPart`) or somewhere else in the Eclipse workbench.

So I have tried this code:

```
tree.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMove(MouseEvent e) {
            boolean mouseIsInEditor = tree.getClientArea().contains(new Point(e.x, e.y));
            if (mouseIsInEditor) {
                System.out.println("IS IN EDITOR");
            } else {
                System.out.println("NOT IN EDITOR");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But it won't even run the code as long as the mouse is outside of my tree, so `mouseIsInEditor` will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `MouseTrackListener` listener to your tree:

```
tree.addMouseTrackListener(listener);
```

This has `mouseEnter` method called when the mouse enters your control, `mouseExit` called when the mouse leaves the control and `mouseHover` when the mouse hovers over some part of the control.